# How to write a conditional statement amidst this jQuery script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, mustache

I have a jquery function which targets a rails form and upon the submit event posts the form data to the appropriate action. The object that’s created, a review, is then returned and via a mustache template is appended to a selected element and rendered:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.new_review').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var reviewList = $(this).siblings('ul’);
        $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(review){
            var newReview = Mustache.render($('#review_template').html(), review);
            reviewList.append(newReview);
        });
    });
});
```

I have in my reviews controller written an if else statement in order to restrict a user (a devise model) to only being able to create one review:

```
def create
    @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:restaurant_id])
    @review = @restaurant.reviews.new(params[:review].permit(:thoughts, :rating))

    if @restaurant.reviews.find_by user_id: current_user.id
        flash[:notice] = "You already reviewed this restaurant!” 
        redirect_to '/restaurants’
    else
        @review.user = current_user
        @review.save
        redirect_to '/restaurants' unless request.xhr?
    end
end
```

However I now need to insert a conditional into my jquery to ensure that it only attempts to append a new object if a review object is actually returned after the post action. I’m thinking that this needs to be written into the third argument on the post function but am a bit lost as to how to go about it.

Could anyone whether this is indeed the right way to go about what i’m trying to achieve and how exactly I could write this. Thanks in advance from a JS newbie.

Comment: Why are you using `’`? in line `$(this).siblings('ul’)`?

Comment: Are the curly quotes in your actual code, or were they copying errors?

Comment: Add something like `if (review != '')` around the body of the callback function.

Comment: No they're actually copying errors, they're not in my actual code. I have however answered my own question very simply, could have sworn i wrote the exact same code 20mins ago and it didn't work, but must be my bad somewhere along the line. The below now works perfectly with one simple if statement in the post function:

Comment: if review 
        reviewList.append(newReview);
    });

Comment: Thanks Barmar, it got me all a bit confused with the deep nesting that was going on in there i think. I posted my answer which works well. Any thoughts on whether it would be written in any better way or do you think it looks just fine?

Answer (score 0):

The below now works perfectly with one simple if statement in the post function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.new_review').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var reviewList = $(this).siblings('ul');
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(review){
      var newReview = Mustache.render($('#review_template').html(), review);
      if review 
        reviewList.append(newReview);
    });
  });
});
```